# R vectorizing for loops that run on matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization

Below code assigns a random value between 0 to 1 to each matrix element that is equal to 1. My actual matrix is very large and below code takes a lot of time to run. How can i make it faster. Please note that each cell that is 1 should get a random value between 0 to 1. I dont want all cells to get a same value

```
#convert black pixels to a random color between 0 to 1

mat1=matrix(c(1,1,0,0.5,1,0.4),nrow=2)
collection=c()
value=0
mat1
mat1==1
for (counter1 in (1:nrow(mat1)))
{
  for (counter2 in (1:ncol(mat1)))
  {
    if(mat1[counter1,counter2]==1){value=runif(1,0,1);mat1[counter1,counter2]=value;collection=c(collection,value)}
  }
}
mat1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One line is all that’s needed:

```
mat1[mat1 == 1] = runif(sum(mat1 == 1), 0, 1)
```

`mat1 == 1` selects all elements in the matrix equal to 1. `sum(…)` gives you the number of these elements, so that `runif(…)` can generate the desired number of random values.

Finally, by using element assignment (`mat1[mat1 == 1] = …`), we replace only the elements with value 1 by the newly generated random values.